# How to convert any object to string and string to that object again C#

Tags: c#

i have a string type list and i want to store in text file. For sake of this i want that my list is easily convert to string and i will store it to text file then i read the string from file and convert come back to object and can be used easily

here is code :

```
 List<string> obj_lst = new List<string>();
 List<string> obj_lst_2 = new List<string>();

 obj_lst.Add("Usm");
 obj_lst.Add("Usm");


 string str = obj_lst.ToString();


 Object obj = (Object)str;

 obj_lst_2 = (List<string>)obj;
```

Comment: Look up "serialization".

Comment: Look into serializing objects

Comment: See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx for example.

Comment: thanks a lot i have done this using serialization